# How do you watch HTTP requests an iPhone app is making?

Tags: iphone, http

Just the same way you can open the web inspector or activity window in Safari on your laptop and see all the HTTP requests any website has made, how do you do that on the iphone for an iPhone app, if the iPhone app is using HTML5 (or even if it's a native app)?

Answer (score 12):

indeed if you download charles and follow the instruction on this page (under iphone). You can monitor the http requests that your iPhone

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/

Answer (score 10):

The easiest method is to install a debugging proxy and point your iPhone to it (specify the proxy address in the settings for the wifi network). Obviously, this'll only work over wifi and not via a cellular data connection. You'll then have access to all of the http(s) requests and responses sent and received by your iPhone.

As several commenters have mentioned (thanks!), a popular option is [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com), which supports Windows, macOS and Linux. There's also [Paros](https://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/files/Paros/), which is written in Java so will run on most platforms, but it was last updated in 2006.

Comment: Charles proxy should also work. It seems to be more recently updated than Paros.

Comment: On Windows, you can probably use Fiddler2 proxy.

Comment: I just used [Burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/) and the [tutorial on TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/02/21/how-to-inspect-ioss-http-traffic-without-spending-a-dime/).  it worked like a charm to see all http requests.

Comment: Indeed worked like a charm and was relatively quick and easy to get started. I did have to install the Charles SSL certificate on my iPhone before my iOS apps would accept it. Now I can inspect the headers that the iOS apps on my iPhone are sending to the respective server, see https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/#qa_d8cfd0e2-9e2c-4f53-8383-248d52a82f5e and https://www.google.com/search?q=review+profile+in+settings+app+iphone&oq=review+profile+in+settings+&aqs=chrome.2.0i512j69i57j0i512j0i22i30l4j0i390.5809j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

To watch the http(s) traffic, you will need to intercept the network traffic travelling between your iPhone and your Internet Service Provider (ISP).

To do this you need to set your phone to use WiFi and to pass network traffic through a proxy. Proxies include [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org) and [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).

A good proxy will offer log files and allow you to see server addresses and, if not encrypted, requested URLs.

Answer (score 4):

Mitmproxy will also work for SSL connections, and even has a [tutorial](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/certinstall/ios.html) specific to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also [use Postman to capture HTTP requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/). There's also [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to web apps on mobile Safari:

Besides the proxy method, these iOS apps/tools might be helpful, I've not used them though:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mihtool/id584739126?ls=1&mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/httpwatch-basic-http-sniffer/id658886056?mt=8

or use the remote debugging feature of Safari:

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/