# How to capture requests of app on ios

Tags: ios, network

I want to see all requests to local network that some app(broadlink E-Control) is doing. I want to see how the app communicate with other devices. P.S:I can modify this network and it's on ios not on macos.

Comment: Always on StackExchange projects all my questions closed but doesn't help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The [tour] can help you if you get questions closed or voted as not showing research effort. The [help] has a lot of info, but check on the closed questions portion since you seem to run up against that with one as brief as this (and the duplicate I linked to).

Comment: @Rostcraft Have you been able to figure this out? I would like to see the actual requests like you see in the address bar of a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rely on Charles Proxy for web analysis. It's not clear if that's all you need - but it's a great start for many apps that call API.

- [How do you watch HTTP requests an iPhone app is making?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18108/how-do-you-watch-http-requests-an-iphone-app-is-making)

If you need actual packet capture, Apple describes how to do that on macOS / iOS / iPadOS and other operating systems here:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace